# How can I put the result of a calculation to be put in a list?

Tags: python, list

```
while seed != 1.0:
    if (seed % 2 == 0) :
        seed = seed / 2 
    else:
        seed = seed * 3 + 1
```

I want to put the Result of the Calculation to be put in a list.
Could I use return?
If yes how?

Comment: You can use *return* to terminate and (optionally) return a value (or values) from a function

Comment: Luca_1905, did you try referring to resources on Python's list? A simple google search would show you how to work with lists - https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp, https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list. It would be better to go through tutorials/courses, google properly and ask only if you don't find anything.

Comment: This is the Collatz sequence from the [Collatz Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) so should be done with integers not floats.  I suggest two changes: 1) change 1.0 to 1 in the while loop and 2) use integer division.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the list method `append`

```py
results = []
while seed != 1.0:
    if (seed % 2 == 0) :
        seed = seed / 2 
    else:
        seed = seed * 3 + 1
    results.append(seed)
print(results)
```

Output for `seed = 50`: `[25.0, 76.0, 38.0, 19.0, 58.0, 29.0, 88.0, 44.0, 22.0, 11.0, 34.0, 17.0, 52.0, 26.0, 13.0, 40.0, 20.0, 10.0, 5.0, 16.0, 8.0, 4.0, 2.0, 1.0]`

Note: the `return` keyword can only be used in functions and will only be useful in this example **if this is in a function** at the end instead of `print(results)`

```py
def three_n_plus_one(seed):
    results = []
    while seed != 1.0:
        if (seed % 2 == 0) :
            seed = seed / 2 
        else:
            seed = seed * 3 + 1
        results.append(seed)
    return results
```

You can call the function like this:

```py
print(three_n_plus_one(50))
```

It gives the same output - `[25.0, 76.0, 38.0, 19.0, 58.0, 29.0, 88.0, 44.0, 22.0, 11.0, 34.0, 17.0, 52.0, 26.0, 13.0, 40.0, 20.0, 10.0, 5.0, 16.0, 8.0, 4.0, 2.0, 1.0]`